# React multiple mappings on same level key-prop-problem

Tags: reactjs

I have parent objects that have child objects, that i want to list out with tr on the same level in a table (same tr). But i keep getting this error message in console: "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop". How do i solve this?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.nodes == null ? (
  <></>
) : this.state.nodes.calcNodes != null ? (
  this.state.nodes.calcNodes.map(a => [
    <tr key={a.id} className="topNode">
      <th>{a.name}</th>
      <td>{a.amount}</td>
    </tr>,
    a.calcChildNodes != null && a.calcChildNodes.length ? (
      a.calcChildNodes.map(b => (
        <tr key={b.id} className="childNode">
          <td>{a.name}</td>
          <td>{a.amount}</td>
        </tr>
      ))
    ) : (
      <></>
    )
  ])
) : (
  <></>
)}
  </tbody>
</table>;
```

Comment: why do you need this?  <></>

Comment: better use `null` instead of <></>

Comment: Are you sure that b.ids and a.ids are unique?

Comment: Thanks @Justcode!

Answer (score 1):

this is a warning, you just need to specify an key

```html
<div key={some unique value}>...</div>
```

Remeber in above case div is a parent component
[You Can Learn More here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<></>` is removable, please remove it from your code and you should see this warning disappeared. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) is the react discussion about keys.

If you need to this in certain scenario, use `return null` instead. <> is a tag which tells react to handle its state on DOM.